# Using github actions to create a folder and upload it to a destination

Tags: github-actions

Im running a job that creates a folder `dist` and another job that depends on the first one to be completed successfully to upload the `dist` folder. However I'm getting an error when uploading saying the directory doesn't exist, while it works to create the folder locally and push it to github. I don't want to push the folder to my repo is there a way to work?

```
name: Build Artifcats and Upload To Azure Blob Storage
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_on_win:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@master
      with:
        node-version: 14.2.0
Running Scripts**......... 

  upload:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build_on_win   (Notice here I'm waiting for the artifacts to be built)
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: bacongobbler/azure-blob-storage-upload@v1.2.0
        with:
          source_dir: ./solutions/app/dist
          container_name: 'app/latest'
          connection_string: .......
          sync: true
```

Comment: Folders aren't shared between jobs. To achieve what you want, you will need to upload the `dist` directory as an **artifact**  (using the [upload action](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) then download this artifact on the second job with the [downlod artifact](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) before performing the action you want on the second job. You can find more information on the [GHA official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow)

Comment: You're weIcome! I added the answet as official answer 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folders (and files) aren't shared between jobs.

To achieve what you want, you will need to upload the `dist` directory as an **artifact** (using the [upload action](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) then download this artifact on the second job with the [download action](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact) before performing the action you want on the second job.

You can find more information on the [GHA official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow).